# You have an array of integers, and for each index you want to find the product of every integer except the integer at that index

Tags: arrays, ruby, big-o, complexity-theory, greedy

I was going over some interview questions and came across this one at a website. I have come up with a solution in Ruby, and I wish to know if it is efficient and an acceptable solution. I have been coding for a while now, but never concentrated on complexity of a solution before. Now I am trying to learn to minimize the time and space complexity.

**Question:** 
You have an array of integers, and for each index you want to find the product of every integer except the integer at that index.

**Example:**

```
arr = [1,2,4,5]
result = [40, 20, 10, 8]

# result = [2*4*5, 1*4*5, 1*2*5, 1*2*4]
```

With that in mind, I came up with this solution.

**Solution:**

```
def find_products(input_array)
    product_array = []
    input_array.length.times do |iteration|
        a = input_array.shift
        product_array << input_array.inject(:*)
        input_array << a
    end
    product_array
end

arr = find_products([1,7,98,4])
```

From what I understand, I am accessing the array as many times as its length, which is considered to be terrible in terms of efficiency and speed. I am still unsure on what is the complexity of my solution.

Any help in making it more efficient is appreciated and if you can also tell the complexity of my solution and how to calculate that, it will be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def product_of_others(arr)
  case arr.count(0)
  when 0
    total = arr.reduce(1,:*)
    arr.map { |n| total/n }
  when 1
    ndx_of_0 = arr.index(0)
    arr.map.with_index do |n,i|
      if i==ndx_of_0
        arr[0,ndx_of_0].reduce(1,:*) * arr[ndx_of_0+1..-1].reduce(1,:*)
      else
        0
      end
    end
  else
    arr.map { 0 }
  end
end

product_of_others [1,2,4,5]  #=> [40, 20, 10, 8]
product_of_others [1,-2,0,5] #=> [0, 0, -10, 0]
product_of_others [0,-2,4,5] #=> [-40, 0, 0, 0] 
product_of_others [1,-2,4,0] #=> [0, 0, 0, -8]
product_of_others [1,0,4,0]  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0]
product_of_others []         #=> []
```

For the case where `arr` contains no zeroes I used `arr.reduce(1,:*)` rather than `arr.reduce(:*)` in case the array is empty. Similarly, if `arr` contains one zero, I used `.reduce(1,:*)` in case the zero was at the beginning or end of the array.

Comment: The single-zero case is incorrect here, for `[1,-2,0,5]`, the answer should be `[0,0,-10,0]`. Line 9 should be `a.map { |n| n.zero? ? total : 0 }`. Other than that, though, the time-complexity is good.

Comment: @philomory, thanks. I performed the necessary repairs.

Comment: Mmh, now my solution is basically the same as yours, @CarySwoveland :|

Answer (score 2):

## For inputs not containing zeros (for others, see below)

Easiest (and relatively efficient) to me seems to first get the total product:

```
total_product = array.inject(1){|product, number| product * number}
```

And then map each array element to the `total_product` divided by the element:

```
result = array.map {|number| total_product / number}
```

After initial calculation of `total_product = 1*2*4*5` this will calculate

```
result = [40/1, 40/2, 40/4, 40/5]
```

As far as I remember this sums up to O(n) [creating total product: touch each number once] + O(n) [creating one result per number: touch each number once]. (*correct me if i am wrong*)

**Update**

As @hirolau and @CarySwoveland pointed out, there is a problem if you have (exactly 1) 0 in the input, thus:

## For inputs containing zeros (workaroundish, but borrows performance benefit and complexity class)

```
zero_count = array.count{|number| number == 0}
if zero_count == 0
  # as before
elsif zero_count == 1
  # one zero in input, result will only have 1 non-zero
  nonzero_array = array.reject{|n| n == 0}
  total_product = nonzero_array.inject(1){|product, number| product * number}
  result = array.map do |number|
    (number == 0) ? total_product : 0
  end
else
  # more than one zero? All products will be zero!
  result = array.map{|_| 0}
end
```

Sorry that this answer by now basically equals @CarySwoveland, but I think my code is more explicit.
Look at the comments about further performance considerations.

Comment: This is a very nice solution IF you are sure none of the values will be 0.

Comment: oh you are right, should have read @Cory Swovelands (excellent, as always) answer completely (honestly it looked too cody to me :) )

Comment: You can produce zero count while calculating the total_product, thus accessing the array only once initially. I mean in some programming language where performance matters, there's no point to bother in ruby anyway, your solution is good and showing how to avoid O(n*n) nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
arr = [1,2,4,5]

result = arr.map do |x|
  new_array = arr.dup  # Create a copy of original array
  new_array.delete_at(arr.index(x)) # Remove an instance of the current value
  new_array.inject(:*) # Return the product.
end

p result  # => [40, 20, 10, 8]
```

Comment: That's as inefficient as OP's way, having O(n*n) too.

Answer (score -2):

I not know ruby, but, accessing an array is O(1), that means that is in constant time, so the complexity of your algorithm is O(n), it is very good. I don't think that a better solution can be found in terms of complexity. The real speed is another issue, but that solution is fine

Comment: This is incorrect. `inject` loops the array, an O(n) operation. Since he calls inject n times, his algorithm is O(n^2).